# using VB6 executing a batch passing two arguments, two variables seperated by a space

Tags: vb6

I am attempting to execute a batch file with two arguments from vb6.

```
Shell ("c:\tftp\Createplkstart.txt.bat " & strMsg & " " & cfgSaved & switchIP)
```

however it seems to drop the second and third arguments.
If I do a msgbox :

```
MsgBox "\c:\tftp\Createplkstart.txt.bat " & strstart & " " & cfgSaved
```

it returns two lines with the space " ".

thanks for any advice

Comment: `MsgBox` out your variables. How would we know what is in them?

Comment: Your variables do not contain what you think they contain.

Comment: Use VB's `Debug.Print` command to output your variables to the debug window immediately before your `Shell` statement, e.g. `Debug.Print "strstart : "; strstart`. As the other commenters suggested, most likely the values of those variables aren't holding the expected values.

Comment: Follow the advice above and also note that your attempt with the msgbox does not match your shell command.  It would also be nice if you'd respond to the people who have taken the time to offer you advice.  msgbox is going to word-wrap so that's not a good debugging method.  Assign the text to a single variable as suggested then debug.print that value.  Finally you don't state what the results are of the shell command, only that the msgbox is incorrect.